# Select the right context for the OUTLINER using PYTHON and QT

Tags: python, qt, blender

I have the following code :

```
def make_override_editable():

    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == "OUTLINER":
            ctx = bpy.context.copy()
            ctx["area"] = area
            with bpy.context.temp_override(area=area):
                print(bpy.context.area.type)
                bpy.ops.outliner.liboverride_operation(
                    type="OVERRIDE_LIBRARY_CREATE_HIERARCHY",
                    selection_set="SELECTED_AND_CONTENT",
                )
```

The following line when is ran through the script :

```
print(bpy.context.area.type)
```

outputs OUTLINER

but I still get the error that I have the incorrect context :

`RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.outliner.liboverride_operation.poll() failed, context is incorrect`

which normally works in blender text editor with 3 lines :

```
bpy.context.area.type = 'OUTLINER'
bpy.ops.outliner.liboverride_operation(type="OVERRIDE_LIBRARY_CREATE_HIERARCHY",selection_set="SELECTED_AND_CONTENT")
bpy.context.area.type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'
```

I'm using python in a much more complex script with QT.

any suggestions ?
I'm trying to make a linked skeleton (Armature) editable so I can change it's pose.

I've also searched for a low level function that I can use, but did not had any success.

or perhaps is there another method to LINK and animation to a LINKED Armature ?

I've tried this :

```
def make_override_editable():

    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == "OUTLINER":
            ctx = bpy.context.copy()
            ctx["area"] = area
            with bpy.context.temp_override(area=area):
                print(bpy.context.area.type)
                bpy.ops.outliner.liboverride_operation(
                    type="OVERRIDE_LIBRARY_CREATE_HIERARCHY",
                    selection_set="SELECTED_AND_CONTENT",
                )
```

And was expecting to have this

```
bpy.ops.outliner.liboverride_operation(type="OVERRIDE_LIBRARY_CREATE_HIERARCHY",selection_set="SELECTED_AND_CONTENT")
```

Comment: I found a workaround. operators don't work well with QT in blender, so I had to get rid of them and use low level functions.

Answer (score 0):

this works even if the Armature is linked.
no need to use operators.

```
# Reset the Armature to the default POSE.
for n in bpy.context.object.pose.bones:
    n.location = (0, 0, 0)
    n.rotation_quaternion = (1, 0, 0, 0)
    n.rotation_axis_angle = (0, 0, 1, 0)
    n.rotation_euler = (0, 0, 0)
    n.scale = (1, 1, 1)
```